# What's the easiest way to force Idea to generate the R.Java file?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am trying to run Android sample applications using intellij idea and R.Java file is missing form notepad samples source directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have a `gen` folder in your project root. If you don't, make one yourself.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question. `build/generated` exists, `BuildConfig.java` was generated but `R.java` is missing. — Is there a way to **force** the generation. A command line tool perhaps?

Answer (score 15):

Make sure you have the right settings: project structure -> Facets -> Android -> yourproject -> compiler

Check compile resources by IDE and Regenerate R.java when resources are changed.

This stole most of my morning, hopefully I'll save someone else some time:)

Comment: Also make sure you have linked your Module of your Project to a specific library of the Android SDK, for example API 8.

Answer (score 4):

Use Build | Make. Actually, IDEA generates R.java file automatically every time you make a change in any XML file under the /res directory.

UPDATE: /gen directory must be present in the project and also configured as a Source root in IDEA module so that it can resolve the IDs in your source code.

Comment: No IDEA doesn't generates R.java file automatically **every time**. IDEA only generates the `R.java` if everything works flawlessly. But sometimes stuff doesn't work flawlessly. And then it would be helpful of there was a way to **force** the generation of `R.java`.

Answer (score 1):

`Build -> Compile 'R.java'`

or simply `Ctrl+Shift+F9`.

Comment: You can't compile `R.java` if the file hasn't been generated to begin with. This is also not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention that, in current version of IDEA 12, the by-design behaviour is not to generate R.java in the generated sources project directory, but in an IDEA's system directory:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99045

> "It is behaviour of IDEA 12, it doesn't generate full R.java in gen folder, it generates it in the IDEA's system dir during compilation."

They intend to change this confusing behaviour, but if you're currently working in IDEA 12, look into `~/.IntelliJIdea12\system\compiler\YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.RANDOM_STRING\.generated\aapt\YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.RANDOM_STRING\production\package\R.java` for the actual generated source file.

Comment: `find ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.0 -iname R.java` — no results. There file is not there either.

Answer (score 0):

Fix all errors appear on .xml files. R.java will be re-appeared

Comment: But — there are no errors reported in the XML files. Only errors in the java source. Notably an error: `cannot find symbol layout` error because the `R.java` file is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to check your imports. Sometimes when your IDE (eclipse & intellij as well) cannot find your generated R class and auto-imports android.R.

**import android.R**  kills everything you are doing in your generated sources!

Cost me 30min of my life...

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidStudio use: Build -> Rebuild Project.

And remember, the generated R file is not in the project "gen" directory.  It is in the "out" directory (drill down to your project).

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. And of course I used unix `find` look for the file. It's just not there. How can I **force** the generation of the file if gradle doesn't do it? Is there a command-line tool to manually generate the file?

Comment: One technique is to delete the entire "build" directory (ie. ".../app/build").  That should force it.

Comment: Of course I deleted the `build` multiple times. What is really needed to answer this question is a tutorial on how to use the **AAPT2 (Android Asset Packaging Tool)** to generate the `R.java` without using gradle as I am pretty sure that gradle is at fault. Well, now that i know that the command-line tool is called `aapt2` i will figure it out eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Also, coincidentally, there is a podcast on aapt that just came out - http://androidbackstage.blogspot.com/2020/10/episode-150-aaptly-named.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IDEA 12 on Windows 7 (and probably Vista and 8), R.Java can be found at :

```
C:\Users\[username]\.IdeaIC12\system\compiler\[project].nnnnnnnn\.generated\aapt\[project].nnnnnnnn\production\[your\name\space]\R.java
```

Comment: That's also not an answer to question. I now where the file _should_ be. It's just not there. How can I **force** the generation of the file if gradle doesn't do it? Is there a commandline tool to manually generate the file?