# r.class error Android studio, I've tried all

Tags: android, android-studio

I've a problem with R.class, Android studio tells me: "Cannot resolve symbol R". I've tried all:

- clean
- rebuild
- make
  But nothing...

In another post here in Stack Overflow I read to uncheck use external builds in compiler in settings, but with the new version 0.8.9 This option disappear. Someone can tell me what I have to do?: D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the R class is not compiling Idea (or Eclipse) wont fix it. This kind of error usually occurs when you version R class (Git, svn). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620593/whats-the-easiest-way-to-force-idea-to-generate-the-r-java-file) might help.

Comment: I read the question, all comment, but I don't understand one thing, at the end someone said "the generated R file is not in the project "gen" directory. It is in the "out" directory", but my r.java is in generated/source/R/debug/appname/R.java, isn't it the correct path?

Comment: yes I have it in App/build/[same path as yours]

Comment: Oooook thank you very much, I've solved with the import of the element by pressing alt+enter, it was so easy hahaha :D